# Why do we need to make file executable when using shebang?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I am a unix newbie and exploring the functionalities of shebang line.

For example, let's say I have a program program.py to execute.

One way to execute is to directly call the interpreter command:

```
python program.py
```

If using the shebang line, I will include:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

at the beginning of file to tell the system what interpreter to use.

Then why do we in this case need to make the file 'executable' by calling:

```
chmod +x program.py
```

and then call:

```
./program.py
```

to execute it,

instead of directly calling:

```
program.py
```

to execute it?

Comment: The reason for `chmod +x program.py` is security.  The OS will only directly execute a file if we have taken the extra step to set the executable bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking two unrelated questions.

We make it executable so that the OS reads the shebang line.

We prefix it with "./" so that the shell can find it and tell the OS to execute it, since the script is unlikely to be in a directory listed in `$PATH`.

Comment: Without './', wouldn't it call program.py in current directory?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I mean in the first case we basically call two steps: 1. Chmod +x program.py; 2. ./program.py, and in the second case, we type in 'program.py' and hit enter directly, without calling chmod.

Comment: Only executables in directories listed in `$PATH` can be executed without specifying their directory. But they need to be executable regardless.

Comment: I just come up with another question (as a beginner...).   In usual case we would execute program.py like 'python program.py'. Why don't we make program.py executable here?

Comment: Because you're not executing "program.py", you're executing "python" and passing "program.py" to it as an argument.